# Long 20 minute startup/boot after Visual Studio Install

Tags: windows-8, boot, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Yesterday I wanted to get back into a bit of XNA so I **installed Visual Studio 2012 Express Desktop and Visual Studio C# 2010**. I also installed the XNA framework (which needs Games for Windows on windows 8) and got it working with 2012 following [these directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881005/how-to-install-xna-game-studio-on-visual-studio-2012). I did the **restarts whenever it told me**. This is when it started to just hang on a **black/blank screen (no cursor) right after the windows balls logo thing ([spash screen](http://0.tqn.com/d/pcsupport/1/0/S/H/-/-/windows-8-clean-install-03.png) - right before log in screen)**.

I did not think anything of it the first time and I went about doing a **ccleaner run of files** and a **registry clean up** (I did back up the registry). I also went through a **windows update** as per normal routine. Restarted again for the updates and noticed it hanged again.

I tried merging the registry from the ccleaner backup but it gave me a error accessing the registry. I *was* able to **merge the registry today** so all is good there.

I have also run through a **Advanced Startup options Automatic repair** but it said it was unable to repair.

I have **uninstalled** Visual Studio 2012, 2010, XNA, and Games for Windows and boot times still take 20 minutes. The computer seems to work fine once it is loaded up. Before, I thought the culprit could be Visual Studio or Norton since it gave me a `Error 8506, 421`; I uninstalled Norton last night and reinstalled today.

My computer is a [Asus K-Series Laptop](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/K55N/) (K55N more specifically K55N-RHA8N29).

What should I do to get my computer back to normal?

**There is a similar issue here:** [Windows 8 stops booting after installation of Visual Studio 2012 Desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/497136/windows-8-stops-booting-after-installation-of-visual-studio-2012-desktop)

**EDIT:**

I did install Team Foundation Server which is Microsoft's source control but I could not get that to work as it crashed Visual Studio when opening projects. I uninstalled Team Foundation Server and Visual Studio 2012 and then reinstalled VS 2012. I got TortoiseSVN instead and set up the context menu commands.

Also, taking a look at msconfig: On the startup selection it has `Selective Startup` with `Load system services` and `Load startup items` checked (I did not change). Should it instead be `Normal startup`? -- Just read when you do the Advanced Troubleshoot (probably same as Advanced Startup options) it changes from `Normal` to `Selective`. I have changed it to Normal but have not restarted to see results.

**EDIT 2:**

I just looked at the [bios updates for my laptop](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/K55N/#support_Download_36) and saw this in the changelog: "Fix the bug that System will show black screen". I might need to update my bios although I am unsure of the current version. Also, I am not sure how to update but researching it now. *Edit:* Unfortunately, it looks like my bios is up to date. The download is for BIOS 217 and mine says 217.
[image: bios version]

**Edit 3:**

After running xbootmgr (suggested by [magicandre1981](https://superuser.com/users/174557/magicandre1981)) I have a nice log file of what is going on. I wish I knew how to analyze this data better. From the log, I learned that the `Winlogon Init` Phase took 25 minutes. I could use some assistance analyzing this log file better to get more information.

Here is a download of two traces I did: **removed*

[image: trace analyzer]

**Edit 4 (4/5 - 6:23pm):**

I was going to try to delete the troubled font by hooking up the hard drive to another PC but it was not recognized on a Windows XP machine with my SATA to USB adapter. I put the hdd back and booted but the notebook and it went super fast like it used to. I turned it off and back on and it went back to being slow. Just thought I would share the glimmer of hope.

**Edit 5 (4/5 - 8:21pm):**

I finally got rid of that f.... pesky font. For future reference, the font was `Kozuka` from Adobe. It took a lot of work to get rid of it. The OS seemed latched on to it and did not want to let go. I downloaded NexusFont and got rid of the whole family but there were still two files left (`KozMinPro-ExtraLight.otf`, and `KozMinPro-Regular.otf`) that stuck around in the System Font folder only visible through the UNC path convention (`\\computer-name\c$\Windows\Fonts`). Had to use a cmd command(`rd /s c:\$Recycle.Bin`) to empty the recycle bin and use a `del` command to finally get rid of the files. Boot times are down to about 7 minutes which is better but not back to normal.

Here is a couple traces from the 7 min boots: **removed*

**Clarification** (8:47pm) - I shutdown and started up and it is going fast as normal now. Not saying it is solved but possibly. Traces are essentially restarts and still 7 minutes but without trace it takes about 3 minutes to restart (not sure how long when normal). Shutdown and Turn back on seem to work lickety split.

**Edit 6 (4/6 12:03pm):**

Good news, fast-boot trace and normal boot trace were fast as ever. I disabled Unlocker from startup and turned off the services for Spybot and Teamviewer. Wamp is the only NON-Microsoft service that isn't disabled (for some reason it does not re-enable the service when it starts up). I have not tried plain restart since last night.

Download both here: http://db.tt/Kw2HVBqi

Comment: is your motherboard a Gigabyte brand board? Gigabyte has a knows usb3 driver issue. what is make and model. also check your startup tab and disable any visual studio item to start on boot up and see if that solves issue. any service not started on boot up will start when program is executed so it is ok to remove startup items (not to be confused with services).  you can view startup items by clicking start, type msconfig into box and open it. click startup tab at top.  also you can check the system event viewer for errors and more info. cant remember location im on linux at moment.

Comment: @sethbuffington My laptop is a Asus K55N-RHA8N29 (https://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/K55N/ - Manual: http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/K55N/E7187_eManual_K55N_K55DE_K55DR_Z104.pdf). Not sure on the motherboard; it does have 2 USB 3.0 ports. I have not had any issue before yesterday and my Asus Updater says it has no updates. There isn't any start up items for Visual Studio. The SRT log file for automatic repair says everything completed succesfully. The System event log says there are 4 critical errors (in 24 hours) which the source is Kernel-Power. Check my edit on the OP as well.

Comment: run xbootmgr to see what is slow when booting: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=158252

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks for this enlightening program! Please help me look at it deeper. I added some basic info to the op.

Comment: I need the ETL file to see what is slow. Zip and upload the file (skydrive, dropbox, google) and insert a link to your 1st post.

Comment: @magicandre1981 added a download link to the op. Is it safe to keep those files out there?

Comment: ok, you can remove the link now. I got the file and posted the result as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, I looked at the trace and found that the ProfileService takes 281s to start:

```
 <serviceTransition name="ProfSvc" group="ProfSvc_Group" transition="start" totalTransitionTimeDelta="281174"
```

I can also see that the HDD is busy loading the file `C:\Windows\Fonts\KozMinPro-ExtraLight.otf` This takes 312s and causes the WinLogon.exe slwdown. Remove this font and look if you get a faster boot. If not, provide a new trace.

Comment: That font is very odd. I am unable to delete that specific file because it says it is in use. Looking into a way to force delete or something. Also what can I do about the ProfileService?

Comment: try to use Unlocker to delete the file. Let us fix this first, before looking at the other issue.

Comment: I deleted it using a cmd thing I found. Also new trace in op.

Comment: The last trace shows the file C:\Windows\Fonts\KozMinPro-ExtraLight.otf is still loaded slowly. Open control panel,go to installed fonts and uninstall the font properly.

Comment: It is not in the list anymore but it may have had to restart to get rid of it. http://gyazo.com/b624848d5d9a01370a93f93dad2d4429

Comment: Really appreciate the help so far! If you need additional logs or anything please just ask :) - All Kozuka related fonts are removed from the control panel list.

Comment: is it fixed now? If not, make new trace.

Comment: Added a new trace this time Winlogon Init is 20 minutes. Add some instructions what you are looking for and what graphs, etc so I can spend some time as well looking at it.

Comment: it is still the same. Open the etl with xperfview.exe (which is easier for new users compared to the new WPA.exe) and look at the disk utilization graph. With rightclick and summary table you can see WinLogon.exe accessing the font file and this takes a lot of time for only a small font.

Comment: I cannot see the font in explorer or control panel. I can see the file when I use "\\computer-name\c$\Windows\Fonts" (UNC) but pc locks up when I try to right click and takes 5 minutes for the context menu to pop. When I delete it takes forever and says I require admin perm. but the font folder does not have permissions. I ran Unlocker from cmd but it did not change anything. I have booted into safe mode but the UNC path does not work. In Task manager the disk is being utilized 100% a lot of the time when I try to mess with the font. I would rather really avoid but should I just do a refresh?

Comment: have you checked if our HDD is fine? Maybe it has damaged where the font is stored.

Comment: Just did a Error Checking scan and it said everything was fine.

Comment: Finally got rid of the font. Still not fixed but times are down to 7 minutes. Check op for two new traces.

Comment: it is better now. But you get a delay after loading the fastfat.sys driver. Kill all 3rd party tools like Unlocker, Spybot S&D, TeamViewer, AiCharger. And also activate hibernation and use the new fastStartup feature. To this trace I posted the command at the end of my guide.

Comment: Good News!; fast-boot and normal boot trace were fast. Uploaded both and download is in the op.

Comment: fastboot is fine (10s resume of kernel and 21s completely ready). Normal boot is ok (40s to UI and fully booted in 65s). so the font was the issue of the huge delay and Unlocker or spybot caused the fastfat.sys delay.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great startup expertise! Such a weird problem that I have never encountered in all the years I have been using a computer. The font was installed with Photoshop and it worked fine for a while after. It is just really weird how it coincidently or not (from installs) latched onto the OS.